# Raspberry Pi not able to find java installation

Tags: java, arm64, raspberry-pi4, java-17, sdkman

I am trying to install Java 17 on my raspberry pi with SDK man. After the installation succeeds, I am not able to use java -version in the terminal and I get this error:

```
-bash: /home/pi/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I have the raspberry pi 4 B with 8 GB ram. It has aarch64 as architecture. This happens with every Java 17 installation.

Comment: You should better edit your question and include all the command you used for installing Java 17. May be one command was wrong and you only think that the installation had succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Please install Java using the official website, not some unheard of 3rd party program like SDKMan.

Remember to:

Add to $PATH variable by executing the following command line:

```
export $PATH=$PATH:"yo/new/path" # note the colon is the delimiter
echo $PATH                       # to check if it worked
```

This process is called "adding Java to your local enviro vars"

Note: make sure you download Java from the official Java website(Oracle) for less hastle, not through your API or choice of working environment software/program.

Comment: SDKMan is not "some unheard of 3rd party program": https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli It is a useful program, and from what I can tell, should have worked fine.